# Selenium code is not able to scrape stack overflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was building a web scraper with python `selenium`. The script scraped sites like amazon and flipcart but wasn't able to scrape stack overflow and ofashion. It is always returning me a blank .csv file.

**Here is my code for stack oveflow:**

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
import pandas as pd 

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36' 
driver_exe = 'chromedriver' 

options = Options() 
options.add_argument("--headless") 
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}') 
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security") 
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content") 
options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt") 
options.add_argument("--disable-cookie-encryption") 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\Setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options) 
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/") 

class_Name = "." + "question-hyperlink" 
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(class_Name.replace(' ','.')) 
web_content_list = []

for i in x: 
    web_content_dict = {} 
    web_content_dict["Title"] = i.text 
    web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list) 
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\data_file.csv', index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

> The above stackovrflow code was solved by putting /questions in the link.

**The code for OFashion site**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
             'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

driver_exe = 'chromedriver'
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\Setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://www.ofashion.com.cn/goods/10001?t=15777838840003")
class_Name = "." + "content-par"
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(class_Name.replace(' ','.'))
web_content_list = []

for i in x:
    web_content_dict = {}
    web_content_dict["Title"] = i.text
    web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\data_file.csv',
         index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Please create a new question post if you have one!

Comment: Hey! just asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573846/selenium-code-is-not-able-to-scrape-ofashion-com-cn

Comment: I answered the question there. Thanks for creating a new question!

Comment: Have you done any debugging whatsoever? I would strongly recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem - you haven't logged in. StackOverflow only shows you questions if you log in - so if you make it so that the program clicks the "login" button, puts in your username and password, and submits it, the code will work from there. (I found this out by taking out the headless attribute)

Comment: Well i have just updated my question. Can you please tell me why it is not able to scrape that site which even didn't required login? Thanks...

Comment: Please create a new question post instead of updating this one!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be logged in. You should be able to do this without much work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573612/selenium-code-is-not-able-to-scrape-stack-overflow')
driver.title
# u'python - Selenium code is not able to scrape stack overflow - Stack Overflow'
```

Comment: Well i have just updated my question. Can you please tell me why it is not able to scrape that site which even didn't required login? Thanks...

Comment: The question is why the `pandas` dataframe is _empty_, not why the chrome window is not opening.