# Selenium code is not able to scrape ofashion.com.cn

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was building a web scraper by using python `selenium`. The script scraped sites like amazon, stack overflow and flipcart but wasn't able to scrape ofashion. It is always returning me a blank .csv file.

**Here is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
             'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

driver_exe = 'chromedriver'
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\Setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://www.ofashion.com.cn/goods/10001?t=15777838840003")
class_Name = "." + "ellipsis-single ware-brand"
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(class_Name.replace(' ','.'))
web_content_list = []

for i in x:
    web_content_dict = {}
    web_content_dict["Title"] = i.text
    web_content_list.append(web_content_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(web_content_list)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\data_file.csv',
         index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the website is loaded through *javascript*. You see that loading sign (with the clothes hanger)? If you look at the top of the tab, you can see that the page isn't loading anymore. To wait for it to load completely, you can use [Selenium's Wait Methods](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

**NOTE:** Please put `driver.close()` at the end of your code to close the `chromedriver` window properly.